# Installation Size of Wine

Tags: wine

Can anyone tell me how much data will I need to install WINE to system since I am running low on mobile data.
I have 1.5 GB data daily on my phone so it's hard for me since it says need 2006 MB disk space so can anyone confirm me how much data will I need.
And is there any way to pause the installation and resume back on terminal.
Sorry if this question seems stupid but I searched for the size but can't find any answer.

Comment: Hey Free Down! What steps are you gonna follow to install Wine? If you let me know the steps, I can try to find the data required to install Wine. BTW, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing and Googling is bad method here.

To install Wine you usually need to add support of 32-bit CPU architecture with

> ```
> $ dpkg --add-architecture i386
> $ sudo apt-get update
> ...
> Fetched 27,9 MB in 22s (1 296 kB/s)
> ```

Note **27.9 MB** in the output above.

Then we can ask APT to run a "simulation" for us to get output like shown below:

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install --assume-no wine wine32
> ...
> 0 upgraded, 252 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 139 MB of archives.
> After this operation, 1 003 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> ```

The above output got from Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS fully updated VM, note the **139 MB** in the output above.
So we will spend **28 + 139 = 167 MB** mobile data traffic and not 1.3 GB as other user states.

Answer (score -1):

The download size for Wine is about **1.3 GB** (for version 5.0).

you can just google it:
**wine download size**

Comment: bro some sites says 21.6 MB so it makes quite hard to know the value. But since you have confirmed its 1.3 GB so thanks.

Comment: Such things should not be googled. Such things should be simulated on the running OS.